# .colliderect not working; why is x and y not updating?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am currently making a game where you run around as a bear, collect fish, and get points. However, when the bear runs into the fish, it does not pick it up as the bear has run into the fish.

I have tried having the function running in some of the loops where the fish has been made and even making it a function but it does not seem to work.

```py
global screen, grasspic, bearImg, fishpic, screen_width, screen_height, score_number, bearRect
import random
import pygame
import sys
import time
import math
pygame.init()

screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480
sw2 = screen_width/2
sh2 = screen_height/2

bearImg = pygame.image.load('bear.png')
bearImg = pygame.transform.scale(bearImg, (150,150))

green = (24, 255, 0)

bearImg_width = 150

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    clocktxt = pygame.font.Font('freesans.ttf', 20)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, clocktxt)
    TextRect.center = (55, 15)
    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0,0,0)
#NOTE: DOWNLOAD FISH, BEAR, AND GRASS PICTURES|| IT WILL NOT WORK WITHOUT IT
grasspic = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    grasspic.append(pygame.image.load('grass%s.png' % i))
fishpic = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    fishpic.append(pygame.image.load('fish%s.png' % i))

fishpic[0] = pygame.transform.scale(fishpic[0], (50,50))
fishpic[1] = pygame.transform.scale(fishpic[1], (50,50))

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hungry Boi') 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

camerax = 0
cameray = 0

def getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, objWidth, objHeight):
    cameraRect = pygame.Rect(camerax, cameray, screen_width, screen_height)
    while True:
        x = random.randint(camerax - screen_width, camerax + (2*screen_width))
        y = random.randint(cameray - screen_height, cameray + (2*screen_height))
        objRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, objWidth, objHeight)
        if not objRect.colliderect(cameraRect):
            return x, y

def makeNewGrass(camerax, cameray):
    gr = {}
    gr['grassImage'] = random.randint(0, len(grasspic) - 1)
    gr['width'] = 80
    gr['height'] = 80
    gr['x'], gr['y'] = getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, gr['width'], gr['height'])
    gr['rect'] = pygame.Rect((gr['x'], gr['y'], gr['width'], gr['height']))
    return gr

def makeNewFish(camerax, cameray):
    fi = {}
    fi['fishImage'] = random.randint(0, len(fishpic) - 1)
    fi['width'] = 150
    fi['height'] = 150
    fi['x'], fi['y'] = getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, fi['width'], fi['height'])
    fi['rect'] = pygame.Rect((fi['x'], fi['y'], fi['width'], fi['height']))
    return fi

def bear(x,y):
    screen.blit(bearImg,(x,y))

allgrass = []
def makegrass():    
    for i in range(15):
                    allgrass.append(makeNewGrass(camerax, cameray))
                    allgrass[i]['x'] = random.randint(0, screen_width)
                    allgrass[i]['y'] = random.randint(0, screen_height)
makegrass()

allfish = []
def makefish():
    for i in range(2):
            allfish.append(makeNewFish(camerax, cameray))
            allfish[i]['x'] = random.randint(0, screen_width)
            allfish[i]['y'] = random.randint(0, screen_height)

makefish()

def game_loop():
    x = (screen_width * 0.4)
    y = (screen_height * 0.4)

    STARTINGX = (screen_width * 0.4)
    STARTINGY = (screen_height * 0.4)

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0
    vel = 5

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change -= vel
                    STARTINGX -= vel
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change += vel
                    STARTINGX += vel
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change -= vel
                    STARTINGY -= vel
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change += vel
                    STARTINGY += vel


            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0


            #print (event) #see events, basically a console, makes a mess
        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        screen.fill(green)

        bearRect = pygame.Rect((STARTINGX, STARTINGY, STARTINGX+150, STARTINGY+150))


        for grass in allgrass:
                    gRect = pygame.Rect((grass['x'] - camerax,
                                grass['y'] - cameray,
                                grass['width'],
                                grass['height']))
                    screen.blit(grasspic[grass['grassImage']], gRect)
        for fish in allfish:
            fRect = pygame.Rect((fish['x'] - camerax,
                        fish['y'] - cameray,
                        fish['width'],
                        fish['height']))
            screen.blit(fishpic[fish['fishImage']], fRect)

        bear(x,y)
        score_count()

        if bearRect.colliderect(fRect):
            makefish()
            makegrass()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30) #fps//may not be safe to run really fast

def score_count():
    score_number = 0
    message_display("Score is: " + str(score_number))

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit
```

Instead of getting a collision and have both the grass and fish images randomize on the screen again, the code will ignore the entire collision. Is there a way to fix it and have it know where the bear and the fish is correctly?

Thank you

Comment: you should keep positions for every fish and bear in separated `pygame.Rect` instead of creating again and againt new `pygame.Rect`.

Comment: you check collision only with last fish on list - because you check it after loop `for fish in allfish` when `fRect` has position of last fish.

Comment: to better orginize code you should put all functions before `pygame.init()`

Comment: all variables created outside functions and classes are global - and using `global` outside function have no sense. We use word `global` inside function to inform function that we want to use external (global) variable in this function instead of creating local one.

Comment: when you check collision you don't change score and your function alway set score 0. And you don't remove fish from list but you only append two new fishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it works correctly but I made so many changes that it is hard to describe it.

Code did't remove fishes and did't change score so it was hard to say if it checked collision. Now it removes fish (and add new in new place) and change score.

Code keeps position and size in `Rect` and use only one `Rect` for every item. I old code Bear had two rect - one to check collision and one to blit it.

In some functions I change names to show that they are very similar and it could be one function.

Every object has `image` and `rect`. When you read documentation for `pygame.sprite.Sprite` then you see that it also uses `image` and `rect`.

```
import random
import pygame
import sys
import time
import math

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

GREEN = (24, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480
SW2 = SCREEN_WIDTH/2
SH2 = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2

# --- functions ---

def text_objects(text, font):
    surface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return surface, surface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    surface, rect = text_objects(text, CLOCKTXT)
    rect.center = (55, 15)
    screen.blit(surface, rect)
    #pygame.display.update() # use update() olny in one place

def getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, objWidth, objHeight):
    camera_rect = pygame.Rect(camerax, cameray, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    x1 = camerax - SCREEN_WIDTH
    x2 = camerax + (2*SCREEN_WIDTH)
    y1 = cameray - SCREEN_HEIGHT
    y2 = cameray + (2*SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    while True:
        x = random.randint(x1, x2)
        y = random.randint(y1, y2)
        obj_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, objWidth, objHeight)
        if not obj_rect.colliderect(camera_rect):
            return x, y

def makeNewGrass(camerax, cameray):
    w, h = 80, 80
    x, y = getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, w, h)
    images = grasspic
    item = {
        'image': random.choice(images),
        'rect': pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h),
    }
    return item

def makeNewFish(camerax, cameray):
    w, h = 50, 50
    x, y = getRandomOffCameraPos(camerax, cameray, w, h)
    images = fishpic
    item = {
        'image': random.choice(images),
        'rect': pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h),
    }
    return item

def makegrass(number=15):    
    for i in range(number):
        item = makeNewGrass(camerax, cameray)
        item['rect'].x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH-item['rect'].width)
        item['rect'].y = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-item['rect'].height)
        allgrass.append(item)
        
def makefish(number=2):
    for i in range(number):
        item = makeNewFish(camerax, cameray)
        item['rect'].x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH-item['rect'].width)
        item['rect'].y = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-item['rect'].height)
        allfish.append(item)

def score_draw(score):
    message_display("Score is: " + str(score))

#--- main ---
    
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hungry Boi') 

CLOCKTXT = pygame.font.Font('freesans.ttf', 20)

# ---

bear_img = pygame.image.load('bear.png').convert()
bear_img = pygame.transform.scale(bear_img, (150, 150)).convert()
bear_rect = bear_img.get_rect()
bear_rect.x = SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.4
bear_rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.4
bear_vel = 5

grasspic = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    image = pygame.image.load('grass%s.png' % i).convert()
    grasspic.append(image)

fishpic = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    image = pygame.image.load('fish%s.png' % i).convert()
    image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (50, 50)).convert()
    fishpic.append(image)

# ---

allgrass = []
makegrass()

allfish = []
makefish()

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

camerax = 0
cameray = 0

score = 0

# --- mainloop ---

gameExit = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not gameExit:

    # --- events ---
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change -= bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change += bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change -= bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change += bear_vel

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change += bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change -= bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change += bear_vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change -= bear_vel

    # --- updates ---
    
    bear_rect.x += x_change
    bear_rect.y += y_change

    keep_fish = []
    for fish in allfish:
        if not bear_rect.colliderect(fish['rect']):
            keep_fish.append(fish)
        else:
            makefish(1)
            #makegrass()
            score += 1
    allfish = keep_fish
    
    # --- draws ---
    
    screen.fill(GREEN)

    for grass in allgrass:
        screen.blit(grass['image'], grass['rect'].move(camerax, cameray))
        
    for fish in allfish:
        screen.blit(fish['image'], fish['rect'].move(camerax, cameray))

    screen.blit(bear_img, bear_rect.move(camerax, cameray))
    score_draw(score)
    

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- FPS ---
    
    clock.tick(30) #fps//may not be safe to run really fast

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```